# Get the size of wrapped text in Label

Tags: cocos2d-x-3.0

If I create a Label in a 500x500 area with wordwrap, how can I find out the height of the wrapped text ? I'm looking for the yellow height, not the salmon height.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Answer of @idrise doesn't work for system font And here I give a **more flexible answer**.

Assume we want to create a text/label which has a **fixed width**, but dynamic height according to text's length. for that you can use below code:

```cpp
Label *lbl = Label::createWithSystemFont("aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa", "Arial", 50);
lbl->setDimensions(FIXED_WIDTH, 0); // "0" means we don't care about wrapping vertically, hence `getContentSize().height` give a dynamic height according to text's length
////
auto dynamicHeight = title->getContentSize().height; // According to text's length :)
```

And obviously  for fixed height you can do similarly.

Hope Help someone :]

Comment: Thanks man. I was looking something like setDimensions for RichText but couldn't find. I like cocos2d-x apis in general, but now I feel that RichText seems to be worst api in cocos2d-x. Ultimately, good old Label helped.

Answer (score 0):

This may seem a little counter intuitive.
First you set the dimensions with an excessively large height.
Calling getLineHeight and getStringNumLines will calculate the height based on the width passed.
You send the width and height back to setDimensions.
Now your labels getContentSize() will return the actual size of the text.

IE

```
        label->setDimensions(width, 2000);
        label->setDimensions(width,label->getStringNumLines() * 
ceil(label->getLineHeight()));
```

Comment: This answer give `Not supported system font` assert in `getLineHeight()` when using `Label::createWithSystemFont(..)`. For this scenario check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

They added the functionality you want:

```
Added three overflow type to new label: CLAMP, SHRINK, RESIZE_HEIGHT.

Overflow type is used to control label overflow result, In SHRINK mode, the font size will change dynamically to adapt the content size. In CLAMP mode, when label content goes out of the bounding box, it will be clipped, In RESIZE_HEIGHT mode, you can only change the width of label and the height is changed automatically. For example:

//Change the label's Overflow type
label->setOverflow(Label::Overflow::RESIZE_HEIGHT);

    mTexto=Label::createWithTTF(mTextoHelp.c_str(),CCGetFont(), 30);
    mTexto->setHeight(100.f);
    mTexto->setOverflow(Label::Overflow::RESIZE_HEIGHT);
    mTexto->setDimensions(mSize.width*0.8f, 0.f);
```